# MySQL Inner Join with Where Clause Issue

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join, where-clause

Having an issue I hope I could get some help with. The MySQL statement I have written seems to completely ignore the where clause:

```
SELECT `master_logins`.liID, `master_accounts`.maID, `master_accounts`.maUsername 
FROM `master_logins` 
INNER JOIN `master_accounts` ON `master_logins`.liID = `master_accounts`.maID 
WHERE `master_logins`.liClientName = 'asfasf'
    OR `master_logins`.liIP = '127.0.0.1' 
    OR `master_logins`.liSocialClub = 'name' 
ORDER BY `master_logins`.`liID` DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

This code tends to list the most recent result, regardless of whether the where conditions are met. I've stared at it for ages and can't see the problem.

Have tried to set the where clause to just 1 condition and that didn't work with the inner join in, when I remove the inner join it shows me the correct result according to my where clause.

Test data:

[image]

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Is it possible that the data is not what you expect? It's an error I've made before. Try returning the fields that are in your WHERE clause so you can see what is there.

Comment: It always returns the most recent row, the data there is exactly as expected but the problem is it just returns the most recent row apart from applying the where clause at all. But I have also tested the where clause by removing the inner join and it worked fine

Comment: Also I've added some test data now

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but the issue is still that the where clause just doesn't seem to apply. But it works in a simple select statement without the inner join but I need to use the inner join.

Comment: Are you saying that it's returning the `100.100.100.100` row instead of one of the other two rows?

Comment: Is your `ON` condition correct? I suspect it should be `ON master_logins.liMaID = master_accounts.maID`.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was the problem. I didn't realize the order mattered, especially as the query was working.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, I suspect you really want all three conditions met:

```
SELECT ma.maID, ma.maUsername 
FROM master_logins ml INNER JOIN
     master_accounts ma
     ON ml.liID = ma.maID 
WHERE ml.liClientName = 'asfasf' OR ml.liIP = '127.0.0.1' OR ml.liSocialClub = 'name'
GROUP BY ma.maID, ma.maUsername 
HAVING SUM(ml.liClientName = 'asfasf') > 0 AND
       SUM(ml.liIP = '127.0.0.1') > 0 AND
       SUM(ml.liSocialClub) > 0
ORDER BY ma.maID DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: No I really do just want to check if it could be any of the three conditions.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you are selecting both master_logins.liID and master_accounts.maID, which should be identical in every row of the query result since they're joined, makes me think perhaps these should not be joined. Do you by any chance have a master_logins.maID column that should be used for the join instead?